# Cover all possible value cases in a function, still have "return type does not include 'undefined'"

Tags: typescript

Here is a simplified Typescript function:

```js
function x(y: 1 | 2 | 3) : string {
  if (y === 1) return "a";
  if (y === 2) return "b";
  if (y === 3) return "c";
}
```

Typescript checker returns this error:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'

Still, all cases are covered. I could have written `else` or just `return "c"` in the last line, but it could be considered less explicit (in this example it's OK, but consider it could be a more complex function that needs to be more explicit about its particular conditions.

Is there a way to tell to typescript I covered all the cases without using `else` or  `return "c"`?

Comment: This is a missing feature of TypeScript, requested at [microsoft/TypeScript#21985](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21985). For now you could work around it by using an `assertNever()` statement to make sure the compiler agrees that your check is exhaustive... shown [in this TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL59ZW). Does that fully address your question? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz Yes feel free to post your comment as an answer, I will accept it (and upvote). Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better or worse, TypeScript does not currently check `if`/`else` chains for exhaustiveness the way that it does for `switch` statements.  There is a longstanding open feature request for that at [microsoft/TypeScript#21985](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21985), but it's not clear when or if that will ever be implemented.  For now, all you can do is work around it.

Assuming you don't want to rewrite as a `switch` statement, you can use the workaround mentioned in the feature request: use an `assertNever()` function to both verify that you've [narrowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the exhausted variable all the way to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), and that the function definitely returns (because it will `throw` if `assertNever()` is actually called).

It looks like this:

```
function assertNever(x: never): never {
  throw new Error("Unexpected Value: " + x);
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
function x(y: 1 | 2 | 3): string {
  if (y === 1) return "a";
  if (y === 2) return "b";
  if (y === 3) return "c";
  assertNever(y); // okay
}
```

Note that if you accidentally make your function non-exhaustive, you get a warning:

```
function x(y: 1 | 2 | 3): string {
  if (y === 1) return "a";
  // if (y === 2) return "b";
  if (y === 3) return "c";
  assertNever(y); // error! Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoDkMBu2AFAB4BciYh2AlJdUVogN4CwAUIolABZZwA7lQzCAolgFZiAIgCq1UgAcM0DABNEANWQAbEBkozEAakSlaAbk4BfTp1CRYCc8QCelAIyIAPogBMvogAzPSIqFBYMGAA5qyc3DDAiO6IALwZiJ60iFgYUCBYSDLIMtZciEkpbumZ-jl5BUWIMgBGZQmVyakZaSEN+YXFEB0VaJg4+EzuVogA9HOIcADWyG629hyO0PBIAF7uXkGBfqGUEVGx8RVVPZnZuYPNJaPcC13VtX31j03F7eVEt0ar1+r8hi0RoCUOhsHgaNI3LN3tgpABCRAAQSwMRAAFsMGAoEtklA3CpEAByMD41rYSmVVBUODE8YwGJgZCtXQYHhwRBKZBYZAEqDYEk8cm86kIykbDibThAA)